ClientWebSocket ConnectAsync protocol
i'm doing this
using (ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket())
{
    Uri serverUri = new Uri("wss://localhost:5079");
    socket.ConnectAsync(serverUri, CancellationToken.None);
}

but on ConnectAsync i get the following exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unrecognized scheme in server address 'ws://localhost:5079'. Only 'http://' and 'https://' are supported.'
if i put a http or https url, it complains that he wants a ws or wss tho
what may i be doing wrong?

Where do you get that exception ? Post the full exception, not just the message or type. The full exception text returned by Exception.ToString() or by clicking on Copy Details in Visual Studio's exception popup contains the exact location that threw, any inner exceptions and a stack trace with the calls that led to the error. I bet the he that throws each error is different.

BTW just using new Uri("wss://localhost:5079") won't throw any errors. Is the error thrown by the websocket server perhaps?

https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client makes life easier

@PanagiotisKanavos the error was indeed server side, an 8 hour debugging session consumed me and didn't even notice. Solved!
